# GRE: Doubt in Quantitative Part: Data Analysis

Tags: means, data-analysis

$(27,x,35,70,45)$

The range of the set of values is 45.

What is the maximum and minimum mean possible?

*I am a little confused here on how to find $x$ as it can be $25$ or $72$ (since we do not know if it is a minimum or a maximum value)*

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I still cannot understand what the question asks. Maybe OP would be so kind as to enlighten us further?

Comment: @may Welcome to Math SE. As you wrote, $x$ can be the $2$ possible values of $25$ or $72$. With each of these values you will get a mean value of the set of values, with the smaller mean, i.e., the minimum, coming from $x = 25$ and the larger mean, i.e., the maximum, coming from $x = 72$.